# Database is not creating using express and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on simple registration page using express and mongodb this is my html

```html
<body>
    
  <form>
    <div align="center" ng-controller="regiCtrl">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
        
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.userName" />
          </td></tr>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
        
          <td><input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
          </td></tr>
          &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <tr>
          
    
          <tr><td>
            
              <input type="button" value = "Submit" ng-click="regi()"></td>
            <td>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
        
    </div>
    
</form>
</body>
```

and this is my controller

```html
lyfee.controller('regiCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
   $scope.user = {};
    $scope.regi = function () {
      //  var data = {User: $scope.user }
        console.log($scope.user);
       
       $http.post('/regi',$scope.user);
       console.log("post request send");
       
    } 
}]);
```

have a look of my server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//Used for open index.html by default(open html page which one will be in public folder)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'anystringoftext',
         saveUninitialized: true,
         resave: true}));


app.use('/', function(req, res){
  //res.send('Our First Express program!');
  //res.redirect('index.html');
  //console.log(req.cookies);
 // console.log(req.session);
 console.log("HELLO WE ARE IN SERVER");
});

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/lyfee_module');
console.log("Connection created");
var Userschema = require('./models/dbSchema'); 


 app.post('/regi',function(req,res){
     console.log("post request get");
   /*  
     var schema        =  new Userschema();
     schema.Firstname  =  req.body.Firstname;
     schema.Lastname   =  req.body.Lastname;
     schema.City       =  req.body.city;
     schema.Email      =  req.body.email;
     schema.Userid     =  req.body.userid;
     schema.Password   =  req.body.password;
     
     console.log(schema.Firstname);
   //  console.log(schema.Lastname);
   
     */ 
     console.log(req);
     
    var schema = new Userschema({
  userName  :  req.body.userName,
  password   :  req.body.password,
  
});
      
     console.log(req.body);
     console.log(schema);
  schema.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Record Inserted', userName: req.body.userName, password: req.body.password});
        });
        
 });
     
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
```

it's my config.js

```js
module.export = {
    'secret' : 'lyfee',
    'database': 'mongodb://localhost/lyfee_module'
};
```

and finally is my db

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var User = new mongoose.Schema({
   userName: String,
   password:  String,
    
    
});
//console.log(User);
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

my entries is not storing in database even database with **lyfee_module** is not creating please help me, how to i can solve this problem ?

Comment: Any error in terminal? Any error send to the browser? Is mongoDB running? Is server running? Is the request reaching the server?

Comment: @NidhinDavid no error is showing in terminal,  and browser is not sending any error, mongodb and server both are running. request is reaching at server but not reaching in app.post('/regi', function(req,res){}).

Answer (score 0):

i think every thing is looking fine just add running port of mongodb in config.js like 
mongodb://localhost:27017/

Comment: add your table name as well and check mongo instance is running `mongodb://localhost:27017/lyfee_module`

Comment: @Daniyal Ahmed by default it will look for port 27017.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a callback with `mongoose.connect()`? I would recommend trying the following and see if you get any errors:

```
mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, err => {
  console.log(err ||  `MongoDB connected at ${mongoUrl}`);
})
```